# What does this vector multiplication mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

How to explain the following equation? The $S_+^n$ is positive semi-definite cone and $S^n$ are the symmetric matrices.

$$S_+^n=\{X\in S^n|X\geqslant0\}=\bigcap_{z\neq0}\{X\in S^n|z^TXz\geqslant0\}$$

What does the included multiplication mean geometrically?
$$z^TXz\geqslant0$$

Comment: What is this bunch of symbols? The only thin clear is that there is some intersection and some transposition of something.

Comment: @Crostul I have modified the question.

Comment: @Crostul $S^n$ are the symmetric matrices, which is a common way of writing this in convex analysis

Comment: A geometric interpretation is that for any $z$, the scalar product of $z$ and $Xz$ is nonnegative, i.e. the angle between them is at most $\pi/2$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: What kind of *geometric* interpretation are you looking for? This is just the definition for a matrix to be positive semi-definite.

Comment: @KlausDraeger I wonder why the positive product of transposition of z and Xz can be used to represent positive zone. For example, in $R^3$, how this happen?

Comment: @mrf My confusion is added in the above comment.

Comment: @Oswin The above defines a property of matrices, namely positive semi-definiteness. If by positive zone you mean the set of vectors with nonnegative coefficients, then that is a separate concept.

Comment: $z^TXz$ equals $\|z\| \cdot \|Xz\| \cdot \cos ($angle inbetween$)$. If that number is positive you can conclude that $X$ maps any point $z$ to a new point less than $90$ degrees away, as Klaus said. Another way of looking at it is that eigenvalues of $X$ are positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z$ be any one of $X$ eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$, $z^TXz = \lambda ||z||^2 \geqslant0 $ implies $\lambda \geqslant0$. Therefore all the eigenvalues of $X$ are nonnegative, which is a motivation of notion of $ X \geqslant0 $. As for the positive cone part, it is easy to verify that if $ X \geqslant0 $, then $ cX \geqslant0 $ for $c \geqslant0 $.